# iPhone: volume of magsafe attachment sound is not controllable

Tags: audio, sound-volume

There are as far as I know two different volume settings to configure on the phone:

1. ringer volume. This can be edited in the settings, and it can be turned on for adjustment by the volume buttons with a toggle called "Change with Buttons" in the settings.
2. phone volume. This is the volume used by the media playing from apps on the phone.

Phone is iPhone 13 Pro Max. iOS version is 15.1. I am finding that the magsafe lock sound volume is very high even when ringer volume and phone volume are confirmed as both cranked to minimum.

This is preventing me from wanting to turn silent mode off. I have generally used silent mode all the time in the past ten years. However, I don't want silent mode off all the time anymore because I am missing too many important phone calls and notifications and I want to make a change.

How can I ensure that all volume is actually controlled by volume settings? Is this a bug?